# Set top property of a div element

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular6

I would like to change a `top` and `left` property of a *div* element.

I tried to modify it using renderer2 and method `setProperty`, but without luck. My code:

```
this.renderer.setProperty(this.element, 'style.top.px', this.circle.center.y);
this.renderer.setProperty(this.element, 'style.left.px', this.circle.center.x);
```

How to modify those attributes?

Comment: Just add css `position:relative`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try it with [`renderer.setStyle`](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2#setstyle) and use the `nativeElement`, not the `HTMLElement`.

Also append `px` to your value and remove it from the property name:

```
this.renderer.setStyle(this.element.nativeElement, 'top', `${this.circle.center.y}px`);
```